# Multi checkbox filter not working in ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have several age range filters done in my AngularJS app.
Of the 4 of them, one doesn't work properly (results don't match the filter), and I can't seem to find why.

You can see a working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/apcRo3jrAOks2FIImHAX?p=preview).

The filters look like this:

```
.filter('five', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return items.filter(x=>x.age<=4);
      else return items;
  }
})

.filter('child', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return (items.filter(x=>x.age>=5) && items.filter(x=>x.age<=14));
      else return items;
  }
})


.filter('young', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return (items.filter(x=>x.age>=14) && items.filter(x=>x.age<=17));
      else return items;
  }
})


.filter('adult', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return items.filter(x=>x.age>=18);
      else return items;
  }
})
```

And in the view I do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data 
    | five:fiveFilter 
    | adult:adultFilter 
    | young:youngFilter 
    | child:childFilter">
 {{item.age}}
</div>
```

As you will see, all filters work except the `young` one.

What am I missing?

Comment: (_young ones don't work, because child labour is illegal_) Your `items.filter` would return a subset of `$scope.data` array, you can't do `&&` on both arrays like that. For example: `[1,2,3]&&[2,3,4]` will return `[2,3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these filters code:

```
.filter('child', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return (items.filter(x=>x.age>=5 && x.age<=14));
      else return items;
  }
})


.filter('young', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return (items.filter(x=>x.age>=14 && x.age<=17));
      else return items;
  }
})
```